# In case player chooses winning door in Monty Hall, Do we need to consider reveling goat 1 and goat 2 as same choice or different choice in solution?

Tags: monty-hall

While solving Monty Hall Problem,

In possible positions/choice table,

There is a case where player initially chooses car (winning) position and host has to reveal either goat 1 position or goat 2 position. Here, do we need to consider both these possibilities as separate choice and calculate the probability (that leads to 1/2 probability before and after switch). Or, do we need to consider both as same choice (that leads to 2/3 probability after switch).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0pOo.jpg)

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Of course it matters which door Monty opens.

Comment: Should add:  it's often left out of the usual statement, but it is important to assume that, in the scenario you describe, Monty chooses between the two worthless doors with equal probability. If Monty "prefers" to open, say, the door with the lower number, that changes the computation.

Comment: It does not affect the probability of winning the car with the *"always switch"* strategy:  if you initially choose the door with a car (probability $\frac13$), then switching after Monty opens another door and shows a goat always loses; if you initially choose a door with a goat (probability $\frac23$), then switching after Monty opens another door and shows a goat always wins.

Comment: Have you read all the other questions about Monty Hall on this website? There have been many, quite possible that your question has already been answered.